# On AWS launching an AWS Marketplace Instance using CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Is that possible to launch an instance from the AWS Marketplace using CloudFormation?

In my understanding the amis are not available from CloudFormation? 
Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my understanding the amis are not available from CloudFormation?

Most marketplace solution actually use public AMIs. You then have to provide a license either using a subscription to a marketplace solution or by bringing your own license. For exemple, Palo Alto (an AWS marketplace solution) [list their AMI Ids on their site](https://www.paloaltonetworks.com/documentation/global/compatibility-matrix/vm-series-firewalls/aws-cft-amazon-machine-images-ami-list/images-for-pan-os-8-0#id2f321596-3312-4eb1-bd2b-1d9805341d93).